# Как обновить библиотеку в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Как обновить библиотеки support:appcompat-v7 и support:support-v4? При использовании SDK Manager, он не видит новых, скрин ниже: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того, при попытке подключить нужную версию библиотеки вручную( в надежде, что существующая обновится), путём происки в build.gradle строки :
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'`
 после синхронизации появляется следующая фраза 
"failed to find target android-23, Install missig platform(s) and sync project.

Эта строка кликабельная, после нажатия на неё, как я понимаю, должно появится окно со скачиванием/установкой отсутствующей библиотеки, но вместо скачивания появляется окно, в котором много строк по типу: 
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml, reason: File not found

И в конце мне предлагают проверить интернет-соединение.

Как я понимаю, у SDK Manager`a нет доступа к интернету? Я пробовал запускать его в ручную, а не из AS и ставил ему "запуск от имени администратора" - не помогло. Почему он не видит новые библиотеки? Или может я что-то не правильно делаю? Объясните новичку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте включить работу через HTTP вместо HTTPS, `Tools -> Options ->`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Еще можете попробовать скачать отдельно самый последний `Android SDK`, и использовать его

Comment: манипуляции со способом подключения пробовал. Под последний Android SDK вы имели ввиду SDK Manager или библиотеки? Если второе, то я искал где можно вручную их скачать, но не нашёл. Буду премного благодарен, если ткнёте носом в правильном направлении.

Comment: @DenisMolodec, я имею в виду полный комплект SDK https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other